# Tinymce html editor dosnt show anything

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, tinymce

I have a ASP.NET MVC, CMS application. In Tinymce editor where i can edit my page's content, editor doesn't show any content and in browser console i get lots of 404 errors 
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". 
More Info:

- The page itself is okay and got all the resources.
- OtherPages are okay in tinymce editor. only home page has this issue.

How can i troubleshoot this ? Where should i look for problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add screenshot or your  tinymce configure code. this problem could be anything.need more details

Comment: I need general idea for trubleshooting, I know code dosn't do any help because it works for other pages

Comment: ok, but screenshot of console will help a lot,  i am going blind now. by the way, i use tinymce a lot time on my project, for this problem, i suggest,check if tinymce.js loaded to page, it may case by this. of check if before of your tinymce configuration code, any error happends, it may error stop doing operation.

Comment: thanks for answer , tinymce.js is loaded, I only get 404 for all the images in page.

Comment: well, you saied tniymce works fine on other pages. but have problem on you home page, right?